# Discussing two people - one of whom is deceased

Tags: past-tense

I am writing about Don and Doris Fisher - founders of the GAP - and their love of modern art. The problem is that Don is deceased, yet Doris is alive. Writing that the Fishers loved modern art is awkward because then I am talking about both of them in the past tense. Writing that Don loved and Doris loves modern art is simply awkward. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get around this problem?

Comment: If you want to suggest that Doris is still alive, you may say "*Doris Fischer and her dead husband Don loved modern art.*"

Comment: @Graffito "...and her late husband" would sound less harsh

Comment: Is anyone else reminded of Mitch Hedberg? "Doris used to love modern art. She still does, but she used to, too."

Comment: This is a little on the creative side, but maybe you could make this work, if this problem is coming up in a large number of sentences: *The Fishers have concentrated their efforts on...*

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the verb-tense problem and say it indirectly, e.g.

*Don and Doris Fisher, lovers of modern art and joint founders of the GAP ...*

Another approach would be stating explicitly what happened, e.g.

*Don and Doris Fisher always loved modern art and, since Don's [insert appropriate euphemism, e.g. 'passing'] Doris has continued to this day to support ...*

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid repeating the same verb in different tenses by saying

*Doris Fisher loves modern art, as did her late husband Don.*

or *Doris Fisher loves modern art, like her late husband Don.*